# How to fix this horizontal overflow with dl-horizontal?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

Maybe I'm doing something really wrong, but the result is aweful:

[image]

Note how the text of `Value 2` is out the border of the panel.
I need to display two panels of the same width, and inside each of them, two properties displayed horizontally with [dl and dd of bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#description).

[Here is the bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/6MtIso2HlV)

```
<div class="row" style="width:800px">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Properties
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                            <dt>Property 1</dt>
                            <dd>
                                Value 1
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                            <dt>Property 2</dt>
                            <dd>
                                Value 2
                            </dd>
                        </dl>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Properties
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                            <dt>Property 1</dt>
                            <dd>
                                Value 1
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                            <dt>Property 2</dt>
                            <dd>
                                Value 2
                            </dd>
                        </dl>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this horizontal overflow? Am I doing something wrong?
My example looks standard. What have I done which is not supported by Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can override bootstrap dt `width` and dd `margin-left` which are iqual to `180px` for this case only.

```
.dl-horizontal dt {
    width: 80px;
}

.dl-horizontal dd {
    margin-left: 90px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/SnawhTGbvU

**EDIT:**

http://www.bootply.com/mg7mkR303W

Just remove `div.col-md-6` which wrapped your `dl`. Also you may keep all `dl` items in one `dl`

Comment: What is 'this case'? I mean, my example looks standard. What have I done which is not supported by bootstrap?

Comment: WIdth of wrapper dl is too small, for example, if you increase width of row `<div class="row" style="width:1200px">` the example will looks fine.

Comment: But why bootstrap keep the two cols in one row, it should makes two rows instead, why the overflow happens? I can't tell my customer 'your screen is too small, gtfo' (maybe I wish I can :))

Comment: I understood you now. Because you wrap `dl`'s to block with `col-md-6` which has property `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/PPQZjv

Are you looking for something like this?

by default bootstrap adds margins to `dd` elements so I just applied the following css to reset that

```
.dl-horizontal dd{
  margin-left:0;
}
.dl-horizontal dt{
  text-align: left; //Align title with content
}
```

Comment: then just remove that line:p it wasn't necessary just thought that's what you wanted updated codepen as well

Comment: Yeah, but it looks terrible without it and the margin which is supposed to make a space between the description and the title!

Comment: Im not sure what you mean but if you want to edit where the title is just change the width of the `dt` element

Comment: That's not very responsive to begin to set width everywhere, I'm searching the more generic approach.

Comment: Thats how bootstraps dl's work innately  its the parent elements that make it responsive, the widths are set by `px` by default

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bootply.com/aAXea5CY2E

All issues is because your block width is to small.